# Make all JS class instance properties emit an event on change

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, getter-setter, eventemitter

I'm trying to make a class with a large number of properties, all of which would trigger emission of an event when the instance was changed,
What are some good options without creating a wall of static setters?

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this._propertyA = "";
        // 50 similar properties
    }
    set propertyA(val) {
        this._propertyA = val;
        this.emitChangeEvent('myClassObjectChanged');
    }
    // I'm trying to avoid creating 50 setters here
}
```

Or maybe there is a better approach to that in general?

Edit: the suggested duplicate wouldn't work for me as I'm trying to retrofit observability on properties, basically I can only rewrite the class itself but not the whole other code that references it

Comment: Use a function instead? `setValue(myClassObj, 'property', value)`?

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: Maybe in a few months there will be decorators in JS and this can be solved quite elegantly, till then all solutions are either hacky or repetitive

Comment: Both proxy and replacing with functions doesn't allow me to retrofit the observability on the class (if I understand the suggestions correctly), it's just if only I could iterate over the properties and assign the same setter to all of them dynamically